# Python Tkinter Frame widget options ( visual & class)

Tags: python, widget, tkinter

I was reading through [this](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/frame.htm) Tkinter documentation and I came across to this two properties of `Frame widget`.

> class= Default is Frame. (class/Class)
>
> visual = No default value. (visual/Visual)

I have tried to look up in google but i can't seem to find how to use of those properties.
What are these 2 options used for and when are they used?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find the purpose of these options in the [Frame page](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/frame.htm#M5) of the [Tcl/Tk documentation](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/contents.htm).

> **-class, class, Class**: Specifies a class for the window. This class will be used when querying the option database for the window's other options, and it will also be used later for other purposes such as bindings. The -class option may not be changed with the configure widget command.
>
> **-visual, visual, Visual**: Specifies visual information for the new window in any of the forms accepted by [Tk_GetVisual](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkLib/GetVisual.htm). If this option is not specified, the new window will use the same visual as its parent. The -visual option may not be modified with the configure widget command.

I think you can find more concrete information (like [examples of how to work with the option database](http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-option-database.htm)) starting from these descriptions.